# 明日、林さんに 会う or 会った ときに、この本を返そう。

Tags: meaning

明日、林さんに (1 or 2) ときに、この本を返そう。
1 - 会う
2 - 会った

I chose 1 in the above statement but it was incorrect, the correct answer is 2 - 会った  .
I thought 会った   means the PAST, so he is saying Tomorrow I will meet him and return his book, why is he using the past form when he will meet him tomorrow, it makes no sense at all??

Comment: Hmm, this question you tried is a bad question. 会う is less common but it's not wrong, either.

Comment: @naruto Would it mean the same thing with 会う? It seems to me that that would mean you return the book to someone/someplace and then meet 林さん.

Comment: Yes I mean 会う and 会った are interchangeable in this context.

Comment: @naruto Could you say more about that please. That seems contrary to my understanding and to the link I gave.

Comment: @user3856370 - I think you should post a separate question for that. It will be too advanced for this OP. The topic of this question, meanwhile, is pretty basic and has been discussed many times. I believe it should be closed as a duplicate.